# Can't get costura.fody to embed dll into exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, fody-costura

I try to embed the dll of a class library into my exe.
I use visual studio 2019 and .net 5.
I created two projects in one solution
one is class library (dll), and the second is console application
both targeted for .net core 5. I selected the console application as startup project.
the class library contain only public static hello function which print out hello.
I referenced the project of the class library into the console application then in the console application i only called the ClassNamespace.library.hello function.
when I compile it, it workes fine.
then I installed costura.fody as described in their readme, i added the to the console project by:

```
PM> Install-Package Fody
PM> Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

Then I FodyWeavers.xml into project folder

```
<Weavers>
  <Costura/>
</Weavers>
```

After that i rebuilt the project, and it built, and the exe is running, but when I delete the .dll from the output directory the .exe isn't running.

Comment: I also miss Costura/Fody. It just worked. In contrary to the whole "publish" scheme, which isn't just a pain, but also rarely does what it is supposed to do. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished without any additional package.
Since NET 5 you have to set **two** options.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <!-- To publish just a single *.exe file -->
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <!-- Specify for which runtime you want to publish -->
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <!-- Since NET 5 specify this if you want to also pack all external *.dll to your file -->
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
    <!-- Add trimming for a smaller file size if possible--->
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
</PropertyGroup>
```

With setting `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` to `false`

[image]

With setting `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` to `true`

[image]

[Documentation for publish single file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file)

[Documentation for trimming](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/app-trimming-in-net-5/)

Comment: Thank you! It worked  

Just adds that with this config it embeds the whole .net runtime and the result is heavy exe (58mb) 
To reduce this size I added
<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
And the exe size became much lighter (18mb)

Comment: @Jake Just added trimming to the answer to have it a full example. Thank you.

Comment: would this work with <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework> ?

Comment: @RaudelRavelo My example project is on another pc. But you can easily try this :). I expect in total it is just working higher than net 5